# requests.get is very slow

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to resolve a DOI like this:

```
import requests                                     
url = 'https://dx.doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/aafd31'
r1 = requests.get(url)                          
actual_url = r1.url
```

But the `requests.get` call actually takes of the order of 10s of seconds up to 5 minutes (it varies)! I tried `stream=True` or `verify=False` but that does not really help.

Comment: sounds like an issue with that site or the server its on or something

Comment: what do you get when you ping this site? What if you use a proxy? 
depending on the site and findings it could be that they are slowing you down on purpose

Comment: ^This. Maybe the site doesn't like to be scrapped? Try changing your useragent sent with the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they are slowing you down on purpose. Try setting a valid user agent. 
Below code runs ok (quick response) for me;

```
import requests
url = 'https://dx.doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/aafd31'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(req.text)
```

If you are doing multiple requests just make sure you do it slow enough and possibly use multiple user agents at random

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://dx.doi.org/10.3847/1538-4357/aafd31')
html = response.read()
```

Comment: I tested and this is indeed faster. Do you know why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135880/python-3-urllib-vs-requests-performance

Comment: @GSBYBF That question doesn't appear to be related, is that what you meant to link?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. My solution is to create a new environment with more recent python version.

Comment: how can you surely say that without knowing what version Jonh is using?